# Using $resource with angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am currently implementing $http for querying data with angular datatable.  How could $resource be implemented instead?

```
function serverData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
    var request = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/datatable/post/'
    }

    $http(request).then((data) => {                        
            fnCallback(data.data);                        
        });
}

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withFnServerData(serverData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this using $resource would look like:

```
 $resource('/datatable/post/').save({}, function(data){
   fnCallback(data.data);
 })
```

Additionally you would need to inject ngResource into your app like:

`var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);`

And include in your HTML like:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>`